# How to know when there is no further responses to receive from server while using SSL_read()

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I am new to socket programming.

This below code snippet is for getting a response of approximately 1 million lines from server. I don't know exact length of the response and hence checking if the response bunch consists of the ending words like OK, NO, SUCCESS, FAILURE, etc.

```
size = 8192;
while(1)
{
     readBytes = SSL_read(SSL, buff, size);
     buff[readBytes] = 0;
     if (readBytes <= 0) {
        int errorno = SSL_get_error(SSL, readBytes);
        throw ZIMAPEXPBadSSL(GetSSLError("SSL read failed", errorno, ERR_get_error()));
     }
     else {
        rsp += buff;
        if(checking_Here_If_The_Response_Is_Complete(buff))
           break;
     }
}
```

This is taking up more time as for every bunch received, its checking if the end has been reached. For example, It checks for every 50 lines every time until the 1 millionth line has come.

I am using OpenSSL. I googled and got suggestions like use SELECT().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with SSL but with the application protocol. It applies not only to `SSL_read` but also to normal `read`. And using `select` or similar will not help here.

Based on your description the application protocol consists of a sequence of messages where the size of the message varies and the length is not known up-front. In this case there is no way other than to read some data and check if the message is now complete. If instead the length of the message would be known up-front (for example by prefixing each message with a fixed size length value) then you could just read the known number of bytes and no complex checks would be needed.

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich. Was following what was given in this: http://www.past5.com/tutorials/2014/02/21/openssl-and-select/ and hence thought it might work.

Comment: @RamKishore: This page only describes the pitfalls of using select with SSL sockets compared to plain sockets. It has nothing to do with the general suitability of using select for your specific problem. Like I said, the problem is not SSL or select but that the design of the application protocol in your case has no up-front length information and instead relies on some end-of-message marker or some other kind of indicator that the message is fully read.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @SteffenUllrich. :)